# Adding external query from website into existing table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, query

Been trying to figure this out for a while, I'm not good enough at excel to see where the existing information is accessing the query. I have no idea how it works but the post made it seem like all you had to do is establish the query and save it for it to be added in.

I copied a portfolio layout from  [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/7m3nvy/ive_created_an_excel_crypto_portfolio_tracker/) for excel. I managed to make a new query that gets all the information it needs and converted it to a table. What I can't figure out is how to get it to display correctly in the main portfolio excel tab. [image]
Below Eth is where I would put in the new row... Here is what the query looks like [image]

I tried to append/insert and none of it works right.